# Split column by separator and delete values contained in other values

Tags: r, set-operations

I have a category column that is separated by ";". I.E Value:

```
value <- "A > B > C; A > B > D; A > B > C > C1"
```

It means:

The current product belongs to category "A > B > C", to category "A > B > D" and to category "A > B > C > C1"

If a category is already contained in another, this should be removed. So the goal is:

```
expectedResult <- "A > B > D; A > B > C > C1"
```

because "A > B > C > C1" is containing "A > B > C".

How can I solve this?

**Note:** I know that there are hundreds of questions that seem similar. But I just couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work:

```r
value <- "A > B > C; A > B > D; A > B > C > C1"
els <- strsplit( value, "; " )[[1]]

my_reducer  <- function(a,b) {
    v <- str_detect( b, fixed(a) )
    a <- a[!v]
    append(a,b)
}

paste( Reduce( my_reducer, els ), collapse="; " )
```

Output:

```
> Reduce( my_reducer, els )
[1] "A > B > D; A > B > C > C1"
```

Comment: i like the way to use Reduce.
how would I have to adapt it if the categories had a prefix (id) this should be disregarded, but it is present in the result? For example:
value <- "c090501221> A> B> C; c090601221> A> B> D; c090501222> A> B> C> C1"
result = "c090601221> A> B> D; c090501222> A> B> C> C1"

Comment: i believe i got it:
my_reducer  <- function(a,b) {
      v <- str_detect( b, fixed(str_sub(a, start = 6, end = nchar(a))))
      a <- a[!v]
      append(a,b)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try the code below

```
v <- unlist(strsplit(value, ";\\s+"))
idx <- colSums(`diag<-`(sapply(v, function(x) {
  p <- gsub(x, "", v, fix = TRUE)
  p != v & nchar(p) > 0
}), FALSE)) == 0
paste0(names(idx)[idx], collapse = "; ")
```

which gives

```
[1] "A > B > D; A > B > C > C1"
```